# Do ships' targeting computers affect missiles?

Tags: master-of-orion

In the original Master of Orion, do the targeting computers help when attacking with missiles, or do they only affect lasers/beam weapons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow, nice blast from the past. According to the [manual](http://www.jonsullivan.com/misc/moo.pdf) it would seem that a ship's Battle Comptuer does affect missle weapons.

> Missile Weapons are fast travelling
>   drones mounted with explosive
>   warheads. Unlike beam weapons, when a
>   missile hits, it scores its full
>   damage. Each missile is also equipped
>   with a targeting computer that
>   improves its chance to hit (its rating
>   is added to the firer’s battle
>   computer). However, ECM jammers will
>   reduce the missile’s chance to hit.
>   Each missile rack has a limited number
>   of missiles that can be used in a
>   single combat. The number of shots is
>   shown in the description.

Comment: As missiles always hit for full damage, its worth noting that getting more than 100% to hit won't help, unlike for beam weapons. This means that with advanced missiles (which have an inherent +to hit) you often don't need a very advanced battle computer unless your opponent is using ECM jammers.